# Index.html file is named as parent directory?

Tags: html, web, directory, server

I have an **contact.html** file on the server in public_html.If I Move it into directory named: *Contact*, & rename it to *index.html*,does browser's Address bar shows it like: **example.com/Contact/** ? I mean the name of file doesn't show up.
ANY help is appreciated.

Comment: This will work _if your have the index module active in your http server configuration._ But the more elegant way is to use "url rewriting" by means of your http servers rewriting module for such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `example.com/Contact/` would work, but only if the server is configured with a default document `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behaviour for apache web servers.
In your apache config there is a directive called

```
DirectoryIndex index.html ...
```

This tells the webserver to serve index.html in the case that a directory call was requested ... ie your example.com/Contact/ [Is a directory].

To change that behaviour you would need to look into change your server config, or adding an .htaccess file that would rewrite the URL to index.html